# erroneous character fixing of strings in c#

Tags: c#, string, performance

I have five strings like below,

ABBCCD

ABBDCD

ABBDCD

ABBECD

ABBDCD

all the strings are basically same except for the fourth characters. But only the character that appears maximum time will take the place.  For example here D was placed 3 times in the fourth position. So, the final string will be ABBDCD. I wrote following code, but it seemed to be less efficient in terms of time. Because this function can be called million times. What should I do to improve the performance?

Here changedString is the string to be matched with other 5 strings. If Any position of the changed string is not matched with other four, then the maxmum occured character will be placed on changedString.

**len** is the length of the strings which is same for all strings.

```
for (int i = 0; i < len;i++ )
{
    String findDuplicate = string.Empty + changedString[i] + overlapStr[0][i] + overlapStr[1][i] + overlapStr[2][i] +
                           overlapStr[3][i] + overlapStr[4][i];

    char c = findDuplicate.GroupBy(x => x).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count()).First().Key;
    if(c!=changedString[i])
    {
        if (i > 0)
        {
            changedString = changedString.Substring(0, i) + c +
                            changedString.Substring(i + 1, changedString.Length - i - 1);
        }
        else
        {
            changedString = c + changedString.Substring(i + 1, changedString.Length - 1);
        }
    }
    //string cleanString = new string(findDuplicate.ToCharArray().Distinct().ToArray());
}
```

Comment: i was in a fix how can i give the title, okay i made it brief.

Comment: No, I am doing a project and for this i needed to use this function. But is taking a lot of time.

Comment: First, string concatenation is expensive. Use a StringBuilder instead.

Comment: If the strings are fixed length, char[] is even faster.

Comment: @BryceWagner: That's a good point. If I'm understand what they are trying to do with the substring part, I don't think they actually need the whole substring, just the one character.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you are going to do, but if it is about sorting strings by some n-th character, then the best way is to use Counting Sort http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort It is used for sorting array of small integers and is quite fine for chars. It has linear O(n) time. The main idea is that if you know all your possible elements (looks like they can be only A-Z here) then you can create an additional array and count them. For your example it will be {0, 0, 1 ,3 , 1, 0,...} if we use 0 for 'A', 1 for 'B' and so on.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function that might help performance-wise as it runs five times faster. The idea is to count occurrences yourself using a dictionary to convert character to a position into counting array, increment value at this position and check if it is greater than previously highest number of occurrences. If it is, current character is top and is stored as result. This repeats for each string in overlapStr and for each position within the strings. Please read comments inside code to see details.

```
string HighestOccurrenceByPosition(string[] overlapStr)
{
    int len = overlapStr[0].Length;
    //  Dictionary transforms character to offset into counting array
    Dictionary<char, int> char2offset = new Dictionary<char, int>();
    //  Counting array. Each character has an entry here
    int[] counters = new int[overlapStr.Length];
    //  Highest occurrence characters found so far
    char[] topChars = new char[len];

    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        char2offset.Clear();
        //  faster! char2offset = new Dictionary<char, int>();
        //  Highest number of occurrences at the moment
        int highestCount = 0;
        //  Allocation of counters - as previously unseen character arrives 
        //  it is given a slot at this offset
        int lastOffset = 0;
        //  Current offset into "counters"
        int offset = 0;
        //  Small optimization. As your data seems very similar, this helps
        //  to reduce number of expensive calls to TryGetValue
        //  You might need to remove this optimization if you don't have 
        //  unused value of char in your dataset
        char lastChar = (char)0;

        for (int j = 0; j < overlapStr.Length; ++ j)
        {
            char thisChar = overlapStr[j][i];
            //  If this is the same character as last one
            //  Offset already points to correct cell in "counters"
            if (lastChar != thisChar)
            {
                //  Get offset
                if (!char2offset.TryGetValue(thisChar, out offset))
                {
                    //  First time seen - allocate & initialize cell
                    offset = lastOffset;
                    counters[offset] = 0;
                    //  Map character to this cell
                    char2offset[thisChar] = lastOffset++;
                }
                //  This is now last character
                lastChar = thisChar;
            }
            //  increment and get count for character
            int charCount = ++counters[offset];
            //  This is now highestCount.
            //  TopChars receives current character
            if (charCount > highestCount)
            {
                highestCount = charCount;
                topChars[i] = thisChar;
            }
        }
    }
    return new string(topChars);
}
```

P.S. This is certainly not the best solution. But as it is significantly faster than original I thought I should help out.